# Ошибка out-projected type. Вызов переопределенных методов разных классов, наследованных от одного в цикле

Tags: java, kotlin, наследование, generics

Игра. У героя есть определенные атрибуты - какие-то значения, которые могут быть изменены в ходе игры. Есть два типа атрибутов - Int и Double. Каждый атрибут должен иметь метод add, при помощи которого изменяется его значение. Реализовано это так:

```
abstract class Attribute<T> (protected var value : T) {
    abstract fun add(otherValue : T)
}

class IntAttribute(value : Int) : Attribute<Int>(value) {
    override fun add(otherValue : Int) {
        value += otherValue
    }
}

class DoubleAttribute(value : Double) : Attribute<Double>(value) {
    override fun add(otherValue : Double) {
        value += otherValue
    }
}
```

Перечень атрибутов героя фиксирован. Все атрибуты должны быть инициализированы и должны храниться в контейнере, позволяющем удобно работать со всем набором атрибутов сразу.
Реализация контейнера:

```
class AttributesContainer (
        hp : DoubleAttribute,
        mana : DoubleAttribute,
        speed : IntAttribute,
        viewRange : IntAttribute
) {
    private val attributes = hashMapOf<String, Attribute<*>>(
            "hp" to hp,
            "mana" to mana,
            "speed" to speed,
            "viewRange" to viewRange
    )

    // метод, позволяющий изменить значения всех атрибутов в контейнере
    // увеличив их на соответствующие значения из входного набора AttributesIncrease
    fun increase(increase : AttributesIncrease) {
        increase.values.forEach {
            attributes[it.key]?.add( it.value ) // ERROR: out-projected type 'Attribute<*>'
        }
    }
}
```

где AttributeIncrease - это класс, хранящий набор значений, прибавляемых к значениям соответстующих атрибутов. Реализация:

```
class AttributesIncrease (
    hp : Double,
    mana : Double,
    speed : Int,
    viewRange : Int
) {
    val values = hashMapOf<String, Number>(
            "hp" to hp,
            "mana" to mana,
            "speed" to speed,
            "viewRange" to viewRange
    )
}
```

Почему нужна подобная структура:

1. к герою будут применяться некие эффекты, действие которых выражается в изменении значений его атрибутов, поэтому нужна возможность удобной работы со всеми атрибутами сразу
2. необходима возможность перебора всех аргументов внутри контейнера, поэтому атрибуты в контейнеры не могут быть отдельными полями класса
3. контейнер атрибутов должен позволять получать значения конкретных атрибутов по названию, поэтому - map

Понятно, что, благодаря хранению в мапе значений типа Attribute<*> и наличию разных реализаций метода add (в IntAttribute и DoubleAttribute) компилятор ругается на его вызов для конкретного аттрибута в мапе.

Тем не менее, **хочется реализовать всё именно таким образом - работать с атрибутами как-то универсально, не различая их по типам**. Не отпускает мысль о том, что, вроде как, возможностью таких подходов и славится супер-пупер ООП-шный код, и кажется, что какое-то подобное решение существует.

Какие решения уже были рассмотрены и отклонены:

1. реализовать метод add сразу в асбтрактном Attribute, который принимал бы параметр Number, а внутри разбирался с его типом - не подходит потому, что метод add не хочется нагружать лишней работой, т.к. он будет вызываться в игре постоянно;
2. если хранить IntAttribute и DoubleAttribute в разных мапах внутри
       контейнера - становится очень корявой реализация метода
       AttributeContainer, который позволит получать значение конкретного
       атрибута по его имени + корявый перебор всех атрибутов + + +;
3. забить на эту "универсальность" и на уровне контейнера работать с атрибутами "в лоб" - хранить их в виде полей класса, работать внутри методов просто с каждым полем отдельно - не подходит потому, что это просто ужасно и очень бы этого не хотелось

Естественно, в игре для всех этих классов предусмотрено гораздо большее количество разных методов и полей, например: класс Attribute хранит не одно значение - он имеет baseValue, maxValue, и currentValue (базовое значение, максимальное значение и текущее) и работает с ними - поэтому атрибут представлен в виде отдельного класса, а не простого Int или Double.

Надеюсь, смысл задачи раскрыть удалось более-менее понятно.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос, изменив методы add в классах IntAttribute и DoubleAttribute следующим образом:

```
class IntAttribute(value : Int) : Attribute<Int>(value) {
    override fun add(otherValue : Number) {
        value += otherValue as Int
    }
}

class DoubleAttribute(value : Double) : Attribute<Double>(value) {
    override fun add(otherValue : Number) {
        value += otherValue as Double
    }
}
```

, где тип входного параметра был заменен на Number в обоих случаях, в то время как  каждый метод теперь работает с переданным параметром соответственно типу поля value - add в IntAttribute "воспринимает" параметр как Int,  а в DoubleAttribute - как Double, при помощи конструкции "as".